# PowerShell export data to CSV in proper format

Tags: powershell-5.0

I get PSDrive information of my computer and put them into table format.

```
Get-PSDrive -Name C, D | 

Select-Object -Property Name,
@{Name="Total (GB)"; Expression={($_.Used + $_.Free) / 1gb}}, 
@{Name="Used (GB)"; Expression={$_.Used / 1gb}}, 
@{Name="Free (GB)"; Expression={$_.Free / 1gb}} |

Format-Table
```

Below is the output on PowerShell.

```
Name Total (GB) Used (GB) Free (GB)
---- ---------- --------- ---------
C        241.21    109.29    131.92
D        233.90      0.10    233.80
```

Finally I try to export data into CSV file with another pipe.

```
Export-Csv .\Desktop\CheckDrive.csv -Encoding utf8
```

I notice the data in CSV is very weird, it is totally different from the original data and not in the proper table format. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Try removing `Format-Table` from your pipeline and directly export the object obtained from `Select-Object` to `.csv`. Maybe table formatting is not suitable for exporting to `.csv` but only for console output.

Comment: thanks @MilosStojanovic for helping me as a absolute beginner in PowerShell. It works. Can you please advise any book for beginner or beginner-friendly project to practise PowerShell skill?

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. I wrote up an answer so it's easier for people to understand. I don't really have any books or tutorials to recommend. What I would recommend is that you make up some kind of project (move and rename specific files, automate some process etc.) or try finding them on internet. Anyway, point is that whenever you write some code and use some command, try to explore exactly what that command do and how it's supposed to be used. Docs is almost always good choice to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that you are trying to use `Export-Csv`, after `Table-Format` which doesn't return object that you need to export to csv. It returns format objects that represent table so it's not what you want. To fix it, remove `Table-Format` and directly pipe `Select-Object` to `Export-Csv`.

[Table-Format output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.4#outputs)

> This cmdlet returns format objects that represent the table.

This is what [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4#description) says about exporting to csv using `Export-Csv`:

> The `Export-CSV` cmdlet creates a CSV file of the **objects** that you
> submit.
> ...
> **Do not format objects** before sending them to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. **If `Export-CSV` receives formatted objects the CSV file
> contains the format properties rather than the object properties.**

Comment: Very well explained. I tested and it works.